# Stacked Area Chart: transition to remove chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, transition

I using the exact same chart as the one provided in this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685 on my website.

I am trying to add a nice transition for when I remove the chart. I'd like the height of my areas to be gradually set to 0. The way I am trying to do it is the following:

```
  var stackedArea0 = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y0(function(d) { return height; })
      .y1(function(d) { return height; });

  d3.csv("./javascripts/postinghours.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = format.parse(d.date);
      d.value = +d.value;
    });

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .offset("zero")
      .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
      .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var nest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.key; });

    var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

    svg.selectAll(".layer")
        .data(layers)
        .transition(1000)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return stackedArea0(d.values); })
        .remove();
    });
```

However it doesnt work and I get this error in the console:

```
Error: Problem parsing 
d="MNaN,0.08960000000000001QNaN,329.....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If the rest of your code is the same as the example, you need to parse the dates instead of doing `+d.date`.

Comment: sorry my bad, I edited the code but it is not where the problem lies

Comment: Well in any case something is going wrong with your x coordinates. Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: What you've got seems to work for me in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/7LvTH/ . I made one change to your code which was to change `.transition(1000)` to `.transition().duration(5000)`